# Problema en la asignacion de matrices en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, numpy

Buenas, no se si esta pregunta ya a sido respondida, pero mi problema es el siguiente:

Al asignar una variable **global** a una variable **local** de una clase , cuando cambio el valor de la variable **local** modifica tambien el valor de la variable **global**. A continuacion les adjunto el codigo.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((3, 3))
x[1][1] = 1

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def _func_1_(self):

        global x

        print("x[1][1] =", x[1][1])  # Primera Salida

        self.aux = x
        self.aux[1][1] = _func_2_(aux[1][1])

        print("x[1][1] =", x[1][1])  # Segunda Salida

    def _func_2_(self, value):

        return (value * 10)


    $ x[1][1] = 1
    $ x[1][1] = 10
```

Como pueden observar en la salida del codigo, antes de realizar la operacion sobre la matriz **aux** el valor de **x[1][1] = 1**, mientras que despues de la operacion el de **x[1][1] = 10**.

¿Cual puede ser la falla en el codigo?

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo necesitas cambiar la asignacion:

```
self.aux = x
```

por

```
self.aux = x.copy()
```

Asi cambias la referencia a la variable global por una referencia a una copia de los valores de la matriz

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tiene tu código es que estás suponiendo que hacer esto `self.aux = x` copia el contenido de `x` a una nueva lista, lo cual no es cierto al menos en Python (y en algunos otros lenguajes). Tienes que tener en cuenta que las variables no son los objetos sino una referencia a estos. Es decir `x` es una variable que apunta a un objeto lista no es la lista en si misma. Cuando haces `self.aux = x` lo que haces es crear una nueva referencia al mismo objeto al que apunta `x`, por lo que cualquier operación sobre `self.aux` va a afectar al mismo objeto al que apunta `x`. Esto se puede verificar fácilmente:

```
x = [1,2,3]
aux = x
print(id(x))
print(id(aux))
> 140621670367112
> 140621670367112
```

Si observas el `id` interno al que apunta `x` como `aux` es el mismo. La solución es "copiar" la lista original y generar un nuevo objeto lista. Hay varias formas de hacer esto, te recomiendo leer [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list). Por ejemplo:

- Usando un "slice", que además suele ser el más rápido de los métodos

  ```
  aux = x[:]
  ```
- Usando el constructor `list`

  ```
  aux = list(x)
  ```
- Copiando la lista mediante [`copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#set.copy)

  ```
  aux = x.copy()
  ```
- Para listas que contienen otros objetos se usa [`deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

  ```
  import copy
  lst2=copy.deepcopy(lst1)
  ```
- Usando comprensión de listas

  ```
  aux = [e for e in x]
  ```
- "Extendiendo" una nueva lista

  ```
  aux = []; aux.extend(x)
  ```

Cualquiera de las formas que elijas el concepto es el mismo: crear un nuevo objeto lista a partir de otra lista y asignar la referencia al mismo a la variable `aux`.